# Who can I add ... at the end of the paragraph in tailwind css?

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind css and I want to add this three dots (...) at the end of a long paragraph.
This can be achived by using `-webkit-line-clamp: 4` but how can I achive this in tailwind css?

[image]

I have tried this but it is not working in multiline.

```html
<h1 class="overflow-hidden text-ellipsis whitespace-nowrap">Hybrid design is starting to become the norm in offices these days with employees gradually returning to their offices. Hybrid design is starting to become the norm in offices these days with employees gradually returning to their offices. Hybrid design is starting to become the norm in offices these days with employees gradually returning to their offices.</h1>
```

Comment: So what exactly are you asking, how to apply `-webkit-line-clamp: 4`? I doubt tailwind comes with a class specifically for that, with the value `4`, already. So add it yourself via your own rules in your stylesheet then ...?

Comment: The official docs covers this pretty well: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/line-clamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding `line-clamp-4` into the `h1` tag.